# Java. How to get constant read times from text file?

Tags: java, file-io

I have text file which contains over 1kk integer numbers. I want to read the n-th number in constant time. I'm not allowed to put all integers in the array. I heard that there is a technique which operates with bytes, so I could just write method "getNthInteger(int nth, int elementLengthInBytes)" or something like that. Please give me reference to this technique, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look into the `RandomAccessFile` object.

Comment: Are the integers of fixed size?

Comment: yes, all integers are bound in the size of int and is 32 bits long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert each integer to an array of bytes of some length L, then write the bytes to the file. L must be exactly the same for each integer. Then to read integer N, read L bytes starting from byte N*L.

---

For example:

You can write an integer to a file as 4 bytes with [java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeInt%28int%29).

You can read the Nth integer with:

```
java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(n*4);
int i = java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt();
```

Replace java.io.RandomAccessFile with an actual object of type java.io.RandomAccessFile.